# iOS unit tests Swift compiler error with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, alamofire

I am and trying to write some tests cases but my unit tests target fails to compile and gives me a compiler error.

The application is working perfectly, only the test cases are not working.
[image]

Comment: Have you linked Alamofire to the FaiUnitTests target?

Comment: Hello @mokagio well later I add every pod fro my Unit Test Target as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanna to use Alamofire in Unit and UI tests, you have to add the pod in the targets, just like that:

```
target 'PROJECTNAMEUnitTests' do
 use_frameworks!
    pod 'Alamofire', 'ALAMOFIRE_VERSION'
end

target 'PROJECTNAMEUITests' do
 use_frameworks!
    pod 'Alamofire', 'ALAMOFIRE_VERSION'
end
```

after that, run pod install again.

i hope it helps.